# How to check page layout from javascript of current page in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, page-layout

Does anyone know how to check page layout from javascript of current page in sharepoint 2013? Ideally I would prefer to not use any ajax calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using below code you will get the `Page Layout` URL of current page.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady(){
    var url = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(window.location.href);
    /* DO YOU STUFF */
}
```

Comment: This is not giving me the right value. I made a page layout, and then made a page, set it to that page layout called `News Item` based on the content type `News Item`. Then the value I got was `/en/_layouts/15/http://mysite/en/Pages/testpagelayout.aspx`.